# How to do facebook authentication in React Native with nodejs as backend?

Tags: node.js, react-native, facebook-graph-api, expo

I have following problem:

I have an App with React Native and I need authentication via Facebook.

I figured out how to do it with expo and the expo-facebook but my problem is, that I also need authentication in the backend, which is done with NodeJs.

What is the right approach to do it, when the backend also needs to be secure?

I looked thru the internet for ours and didn´t find any tutorial...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check Passportjs. It's an authentication middleware for Nodejs. Search for the relevant strategy. Should be fairly easy to implement.